Find if the current date is the first day of the month in JAVA excluding weekends and holiday
I have a problem to find if the current date is the first day of the month, if so I have do some logic. First day of the month should exclude weekends and holidays. Holidays are pulled in a list from the database for the current year
Function should accept today's date as input and give boolean if the current day is first day of the month excluding weekends and holiday.
I tried with this logic:
boolean firstBusinessDayOfMonth(YearMonth month) {

 
    final Set<DayOfWeek> businessDays = EnumSet.of(
        MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY
    );

    return
        month.atDay(1).datesUntil(month.plusMonths(1).atDay(1))
            .filter(date -> businessDays.contains(date.getDayOfWeek()))
            .filter(date -> !isHoliday(date))
            .findFirst();
         //return should compare with current date and give true or false
}

Some examples:
For June, 2024
June1 (Saturday) => false
June2 (Sunday) => false
June3 (Monday and !Holiday) => true
June4 (Tuesday and !Holiday but not first of the month) => false

Please show some examples of some dates, and whether you want true or false` for each of them.

Added code snippet and few examples

Your code retutns date, you examples expect bool as result. What do you want?

I need boolean, but I could get only till here

"if the current date is the first day of the month" but the method is receiving only a month/year... start changing the parameter to a date (e.g. boolean isFirstBusinessDayOfMonth(LocalDate date)

findFirst returns an Optional. Looks like you just need to check whether there's anything in that Optional.

basically date.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth()).datesUntil(date).allMatch(this::isWeekendOrHoliday) or similar date.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth()).datesUntil(date).noneMatch(this::isWorkingDay); alternative date.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth()).datesUntil(date).filter(this::isWorkday).filter(Predicate.not(this::isHoliday)).findAny().isEmpty()

Store the Optional<LocalDate> that you get from your stream operation into a variable, say firstDay and return firstDay.orElseThrow().equals(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()));.

There’s good stuff in the answer. Here’s my suggestion running online.

Why the downvotes and close vote? This question has clear requirements and a demonstrated effort and genuine attempt to write the code. I find it useful.

Given that you need to determine which day is first of any given month, change the return value of firstBusinessDayOfMonth from boolean to LocalDate and return the first matching date from the datesUntil() stream.
/**
 * @return First business day of the month or null if unknown
 */
LocalDate firstBusinessDayOfMonth(YearMonth month) {

    EnumSet<DayOfWeek> businessDays = EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));

    return month.atDay(1).datesUntil(month.plusMonths(1).atDay(1))
            .filter(date -> businessDays.contains(date.getDayOfWeek()))
            .filter(date -> !isHoliday(date) )
            .findFirst().orElse(null);
}

Then there is a simple check to determine if current day is first of the month:
public static boolean isFirstDayOfMonth(LocalDate when) {
    return when.equals(firstBusinessDayOfMonth(YearMonth.from(when)));
}

Example:
boolean isFirst = isFirstDayOfMonth(LocalDate.now());


Good answer with good use of what the OP had already coded. A little detail, rather than YearMonth.of(when.getYear(), when.getMonth()) I’d use just YearMonth.from(when).

@Anonymous That suggestion is a much better use of the API, have modified.

@user85421I used findFirst as the stream isn't parallel and the first in sequence match is needed. Could you elaborate on the benefit of findAny here?

@DuncG I was thinking about negative logic (like searching for a working day before the actual date, no need to scan a full month), just ignore
